# Use either Policy based or Role based Authorization for an endpoint in .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, authorization

I have a role controller with Auth

```
 [Authorize(Roles = Roles.Visitor, AuthenticationSchemes = AuthorizationSchemes.Visitor)]
```

I need to add another policy ***AdminPolicy*** to it but it should work for either of them. Is there a simple way to do that?

My admin policy has a requirement handler

```
options.AddPolicy(Policies.Admin,
                policy => policy.Requirements
                    .Add(new AdminRequirement()));
```

And the handler looks like this

```
    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, AdminRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (context.HasSucceeded || context.HasFailed) {
            return;
        }

        if (context.User.HasClaim(c => c.Type.Equals("administration"))
            && context.User.HasClaim(c => c.Type.Equals("admin"))) {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you share your AdminPolicy ?

Comment: I have added it now

Comment: Since it's your handler, check for the role as well `context.User.IsInRole(Roles.Visitor)` (eg https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authorization/Core/src/RolesAuthorizationRequirement.cs#L56) or add multiple `[Authorize` attributes.

Comment: But adding multiple Authorize does an AND condition instead of OR

Answer (score 2):

> I need to add another policy AdminPolicy to it but it should work for
> either of them

As far as I know, using both roles and declaring roles in the policy via the attribute method is not feasible. Now we can only create a new policy, which contains administration && admin(the same as AdminPolicy ), and then use 'or' to join Roles.Visitor.

In the controller, you only need to use this new Policy without adding Roles and AdminPolicy.

Answer (score 2):

I used something like below, where I needed to combine multiple roles into a single policy.

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("GeneralAdmin", policy =>
        policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
            context.User.HasClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "AdminOfX") ||
            context.User.HasClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "AdminOfY")));
}
```

And then use it:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "GeneralAdmin")]
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are looking multiple role authentication,

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, Vistor")]
public class WeatherController : Controller {
    
}
```

For more info please link look into [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: No I am looking for adding a policy which I have written using a requirement handler