# How to manage different 30 roles with roles based access control

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

In a .Net project i have created authorize mechanism. Except for the login page you can't reach any page. But i have one more problem about that have too many user roles, approximately 30 user's role.
So  i dont wanna write my codes like this -> [Authorize(Roles ="User,Admin,blabla,blala1,blabla2")].
How to manage that multiple roles.

waiting for find a solition my problems

Comment: You can use a policy to group roles:  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71552558/use-either-policy-based-or-role-based-authorization-for-an-endpoint-in-net/72555673#72555673)